# Storing data sets in Django models

Tags: django

This is a django ‘best practices’ question.

I have an application which needs to store a different data set (>10,000 points) for each instance of a model (>10,000 instances), and the data is continually changing (every hour) for each instance.

Would it be best to write them in a file (.csv), and attached them to the model using the `FileField`? Then open the file, import the data into lists, update them, and rewrite the file?

Or, can the data be saved in a relational model on the SQL database? i.e. :

```
class Foo(models.model):
   # info

class DataPoint(models.model):
   foo = models.Foreignkey(Foo)
   x = models.FloatField()
   y = models.FloatField()
```

and then getting all the data points through `Foo.datapoint_set()`

**What is the best way to deal with data like this?**

**Edit**
This is a scientific application where the data sets are graphed and displayed to the users, with options to calculate statistics.

Comment: depends on what you do with the data. If you are reading it/processing it very frequently, csv might not be the best approach. Moreover, if it is just tens of thousands or records, and you just want to dump it somewhere - databases are pretty good. Also, you can look into "pickle field" to store structured data in the database.

Comment: Are you referring to using a package like: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield ?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use mongodb together with Django?  Especially when the data changes quite rapidly.  Also it would be easier to search and run aggregate queries on them compared to csv files.

Comment: Yes, i was refering to that.

Comment: @karthikr are there security issues with using pickle fields? It seems like if someone could send there own pickled file (not sure how they would do that) they would be able to execute their own code on your server.

Comment: Well, you can always handle the validation logic at the application layer.